# ANTLR. How to include information about the offending symbol in the error message using the ErrorListener class?

Tags: java, error-handling, antlr4

I'm using ANTLR for parsing formulas and I have my own custom ErrorListener class that extends BaseErrorListener. I want the error message to include information about the symbol that caused the parsing error.

For example, if I have a formula `2 # 4` and the parser encounters an unknown symbol `'#'`, the error message in the console would be `line 1:2 token recognition error at: '# '`.

However, when I use the syntaxError method and retrieve the `offendingSymbol` and `charPositionInLine`, they contain data for the **next symbol**, in this case, the symbol `'4'`.

How can I obtain the information about the symbol that caused the parsing error to include it in the error message?

Thank you for your help!

I found a way to get the index of the token through `Token token = (Token) offendingSymbol;` but in the case when the parser does not know the symbol, the error message contains an incorrect index оf the next element